# Pop-up window in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, java-5

Can someone suggest me how to implement a pop-up window in Java Swing. I want the pop-up window to be a modal window (user cannot return to the main window when the pop-up is open).

I tried doing it using JDialog but it allows only one widget for user input to be in it whereas I need multiple widgets. I may be wrong here but this is what I was able to do.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a JDialog. There is no restiction on what you can add, you can add whatever you want to a JDialog (exactly the same as when using a JFrame)

Comment: Thanks objects. It was so simple to do this.

Answer (score 8):

1. Layout your widgets in a JPanel.
2. Use JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog with your panel as the message (with, for example, optionType JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION).
3. Read user input from your panel's state when appropriate (for example, the call returns JOptionPane.OK_OPTION rather than JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION).

Answer (score 3):

I hope i found the right info for you

`JDialog(Dialog owner, boolean modal)`

for more information check this links:
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/modality/

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Comment: Apologies for not mentioning the JDK version I am using is 1.5.