# pop up creation java Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout, popup

I have to create this pop up with java swing :

[image]

and I have a few problems :

- I don't know how to set the pop up element at their right positions (should I use a layout ?)
- How to set the back ground color (I am working with netbeans UI) ?
- How to remove the ugly rollover background color.

Could anyone help me ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405039/pop-up-window-in-java-swing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use `JDialog` and `setUndecorated(true)`. For more info read [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

```
JDialog dialog=new JDialog(frmInstance);
dialog.setUndecorated(true);
dialog.setVisible(true);
dialog.setSize(200,100);
```

Comment: you could also use `setShape(new Shape(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height, arcw, arch)));` to make it rounded like in the picture you have.