# Java Dialog Box

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe, jtextarea

How would I produce the following window:

http://postimage.org/image/61aa8hrvb/

What would I use for formatting? Something similar to BorderLayout? Is there a better way?

I have tried using a combo of JFrame, JPanel and JTextArea; as follows:

```
 public static void doListAllChecks() {
    int transCount = CAObject.getTransCount();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    for (int idx = 0; idx < transCount; idx++)
    {
        Transaction tObj = CAObject.getTrans(idx);
        if (tObj != null) {
            if (tObj.getTransId() == Constants.CHECK_ID)
            {
                System.out.println("Check ID " + tObj.getTransNumber() +
                        " Check Amount " + tObj.getTransAmount());
                JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5,20);
                textArea.setText("Check " + tObj.getTransAmount());
                content.add(textArea, BorderLayout.EAST);
            }
        }
    }

    frame.setContentPane(content);
    frame.setTitle("Dialog Display");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.pack();
}
```

I am looking to produce a basic and very simple style of a window. I have the data but I don't know how to produce the window.

Edit: I am not asking how to fill the window with data—just how to produce the window. It seems that it just has a fixed size (length and width) and a border. It seems like it is a barebones window.

Is there anything that you can think of the resembles this style of a window?

Comment: The bottom part should be a jTable.

Comment: you need to investigate how to use the various `LayoutManager`s to get what you want.  a JTable would be good, but you could create your dialog by using `GridBagLayout` or other nested layouts

Comment: I think your Q's A is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405039/pop-up-window-in-java-swing

Comment: Thanks. I know if it was C++ I would #include <iomanip> at least to format the headings..Although the window is still a mystery.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one proposal (it could be largely improved but at least, you'll have a startig point):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String[][] transactions = new String[][] { { "0", "Check", "50.00" }, { "1", "svc.chrg.", "0.15" } };

    JDialog f = new JDialog();
    JTable table = new JTable(transactions, new String[] { "Id", "Type", "Amount" });

    f.add(new JLabel("List all transactions:", JLabel.CENTER), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    f.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    f.setTitle("Dialog Display");

    table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(table.getPreferredSize().width, table.getRowHeight()
            * transactions.length));

    f.pack();
    f.setSize(470, 120);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center on screen
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with a JDialog (as you've asked)

Take a look at [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) to format the content

Take a look at [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything that you can think of the resembles this style of a window?

You might try `setUndecorated(true)`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2166500/230513), and maybe add a one-pixel border.