# How To Produce Certain GUI - Java

Tags: java, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Dialog Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992506/java-dialog-box)

I am wondering how to produce this type of window using Java GUI:

http://postimage.org/image/61aa8hrvb/

I am not asking how to fill the window with data - just only how to produce the window. It seems that it just has a fixed size (length and width) and a border. It seems like it is a barebones window.

Is there anything that you can think of the resembles this style of a window?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a fixed size window? Any UI toolkit can do that. Take a look at Swing. Or is this for a web app? Then look at an HTML table.

Comment: Quite simply, it wastes our (volunteered) time.

Comment: Voting to close this duplicate. Are you trying to encourage folks to not want to help you in the future? Is that your goal? It seems to be working.

Comment: You can edit your original question to clarify. As both answers there are useful, you'll want to explain what didn't meet you requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swing, you can try a [TableLayout](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/tablelayout/)

Comment: In this, you'd be better of with a JTable, IMHO

Answer (score 0):

With Swing, use a JWindow, add a JPanel to the content pane of this JWindow and then override the Paint method of the JPanel to draw a border.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [JWindow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html) to get a barebones window. 
It's simple enough to then add a `JPanel` to it using `window.add(panel);`.